# Setting up passwordless SSH auth from linux client to windows side of dual booting host. ssh-copy-id fails

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, multi-boot, linux-mint

My end goal is to get ssh access to my dual boot desktop from my laptop running mint no matter the desktops state (off,on, windows 10, mint 19, etc) I have ed25519 auth set up between my laptop(mint) and desktops(mint) installation, as well as the rasps-pi i used to send wake on lan signals to the desktop. However getting this to work with openssh on the Windows 10 side has been a nightmare.

ssh-copy-id fails so moving pub keys must be done manually.I know now at this point it's a permissions issue because turning off strict checking allows ed25519 auth to work but this is bad practice and was only turned off to confirm that suspicion. I've followed numerous threads on this site trying to get the permissions straight so that auth goes through but its been a crap shoot. Most of the questions regarding similar issues are solved by changing permissions on half a dozen files but the end result every time I follow them I ended up with a ssh-server service that crashes at start. I'm at a loss.

Comment: I am happy to see you fixed your problem and shared the solution with us. Please set your answer as solution.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. I wasn't sure how to trigger logging on the server side using the windows version and was relying only on client side logs but once I did it made things a lot clearer. I was blindly following "thread crumbs" that all seemed to point to permissions issues as the leading culprit when authorization failed in windows. The answer was a lot simpler.

The Windows version of openSSH no longer uses the same directory structure as the linux version and now stores pub keys and host keys together in the same folder. Commenting out the last line of the sshd_config returns it to nix 
behavior allowing authorization to work if you're keys are place in the manner. I tried this early but not before screwing my permissions up so bad attempting other fixes that it didn't work anyways. Hopefully this helps someone because the search results for my problem led me on wild goose chase that made it harder for me to diagnose the issue which was actually relatively simple.